# Matlab: Dividing by a variable

Tags: matlab, function

Im using ode45. when I declare my function: f = @(x,y) (cos(x-y) - x*y -y)/(2+2x), I get an error: "Unexpected MATLAB expression"

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: To solve the issue add a * in 2x.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be absolutely clear, Jommy in the comments of your post means that you should replace your denominator of `2 + 2x` with `2 + 2*x`, though Jommy should get the credit for this answer.  I'm putting an answer here so that this will be marked as resolved so we can move on and answer other questions :).